# Create definition to integer

Tags: c#

I receive this kind of error:

> int does not contain a definition for 'childConvert' and no accessible extension method 'childconver' accepting a first argument of type'int' could be found (are you missing assembly reference)

In Main Method:

```
int n = 10;
string Name = n.ChildConver();
```

In Child Method:

```
public static string ChildConver(this int Name)
{
    string Namecovert = Convert.ToString(Name) + "Convertion";
    return Namecovert;
}
```

Comment: int.Parse takes a string as input. Chances are that is causing compilation error and thus your intellisense is not able to pick up that method.

Comment: Not reproducible: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VwwEdg - It can actually find the method, but it generates a compiler error for a different reason: `int.Parse(int)` doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, That place I need to convert a string, Now I have converted int as a string and add some string, finally returned the string, but now also I am getting the same error.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Don't forget to write the right `using` directive, otherwise the compiler will not know where to find an extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class.**

Ref: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Define extension method in separate class.

```
public static class IntHelper
{
    public static string ChildConver(this int Name)
    {
        string Namecovert = Convert.ToString(Name) + "Convertion";
        return Namecovert;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to put it in a static class.

```
public static class Common
{
    public static string ChildConver(this int name)
    {
        return  name + "Convertion";
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, extensions need to be in a static class.

Comment: Try formatting your code by indenting each line by 4 spaces instead of surrounding the whole block in backticks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string ChildConver(this int Name)
{
  retunt Name + "Convertion";
}
```

Comment: How you add 'Int' + 'string'.?

Comment: `+` operator has an override where one operand can be an object and other a string. In that case the first operand (object) will be converted to string. Having said that, the code hardly answers anything about the problem in the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this instruction. I will accept your suggestion, but in the child method no problem, The main method only having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try ToString()

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         int n = 10;
         string Name = n.ChildConver();
         System.Console.WriteLine(Name);
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static string ChildConver(this int Name)
    {
        string Namecovert = Name.ToString() + " Convertion";
        return Namecovert;
    }
}
```